# No reference for successfully installed NuGet package in a .NET 4.5.2 project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Using Visual Studio 2015 and .NET 4.5.2, I am building a console .NET project that needs to use CosmosDb things, so I followed [Tutorial: Build a .NET console app to manage data in Azure Cosmos DB SQL API account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-get-started), successfully installed **Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos** (v3.15.1) using NuGet and tried to reference it.

However, the reference list didn't show this package there, and when I tried to use the package in the code, an error "**The type or namespace name 'Azure' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)**" occurred in the project error list.

There was a file "packages.config" which was like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos" version="3.15.1" targetFramework="net452" />
</packages>
```

I have tried to re-install all the packages using Update-Package -reinstall but nothing happened.

What steps did I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution:

> Change .NET Framework version to 4.6.1 or higher and then reinstall the package.